# How to unset global sdk set by fvm?

Tags: flutter, dart-pub, fvm

Global sdk can be set by the command:
`fvm global 3.x.x`

But how do I revert this command?
I was expecting somethig like:

`fvm global unset`

or

`fvm reset global`

In order to unset the global flag what I do not want to do:

1. Set another version as global (`fvm global 3.x.y`)
2. Remove the existing sdk cache (`fvm remove 3.x.x # this is the global version`)

Note:
`fvm global -h` shows only the following outputs:

```bash
Sets Flutter SDK Version as a global

Usage: fvm global {version}
-h, --help    Print this usage information.

Run "fvm help" to see global options.
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, the workaround is to remove the `default` folder inside `fvm`

```bash
rm -rf $HOME/fvm/default
```